# Python pandas: How to alter one column that is (complicatedly) based on another?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have booking data whereas a new row is inserted whenwever a customer iniciates, changes, deletes or reactivates an order. "delivered" shows if the product was actually delivered which is generally the case if the order is not deleted in the last update.

Here is some sample code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
    "booking id": [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4],
    "booking type": ["initiation", "change", "change", "initiation", "change", "deletion", "reactivation", "change", "initiation", "change", "deletion"],
    "delivered": ["yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "no", "no", "no"]
    }
)
```

[image]

Some of the data is incorrect. If the last update (last row of a booking id) has `booking type == deletion`, all rows of this booking id should have `delivered = no`.

In this example, I'm looking for this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
    "booking id": [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4],
    "booking type": ["initiation", "change", "change", "initiation", "change", "deletion", "reactivation", "change", "initiation", "change", "deletion"],
    "delivered": ["yes", "yes", "yes", "no", "no", "no", "yes", "yes", "no", "no", "no"]
    }
)
```

[image]

How do I do this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just did, sorry for the late reply!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `transform` with `last` , then assign it back

```
df.loc[df.groupby('booking id')['booking type'].transform('last').eq('deletion'),'delivered']='No'
df
Out[112]: 
    booking id  booking type delivered
0            1    initiation       yes
1            1        change       yes
2            1        change       yes
3            2    initiation        No
4            2        change        No
5            2      deletion        No
6            3  reactivation       yes
7            3        change       yes
8            4    initiation        No
9            4        change        No
10           4      deletion        No
```

Comment: This and also the solution from yatu both worked; it's just that this one was faster for me. Thanks a lot!
It would be very nice if you could explain why this works!

Answer (score 2):

Here's one approach using [`GroupBy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`DataFrame.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html):

```
df.loc[:, 'delivered'] = df.where(df.groupby('booking id')['booking type']
                                    .transform('last')
                                    .ne('deletion'), 'no')

      booking id  booking type delivered
0            1    initiation       yes
1            1        change       yes
2            1        change       yes
3            2    initiation        no
4            2        change        no
5            2      deletion        no
6            3  reactivation       yes
7            3        change       yes
8            4    initiation        no
9            4        change        no
10           4      deletion        no
```

Answer (score 0):

There is possibly a better way to do this using groupby(), but I don't know that way. The best way I can think of is using .loc(), which you can find a reference to [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html).

```
ids_to_change = df.loc[df['booking type'] == 'deletion', :]['booking id']

for id in ids_to_change:
   df.loc[df['booking id'] == id, 'delivered'] = 'no'
```

Basically, loc returns a piece of the dataframe matching certain characteristics.

First, use loc to get all the ids with any deletion booking type. Second, loop through those ids and change all those ids to have a 'no' under delivered.